# Liferay Search Container is giving Symbol Error

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, alloy-ui, searchcontainer

I am simply displaying records using Liferay Search Container but it is giving me Error : **equal Symbol Expected**

```
<liferay-portlet:renderURL varImpl="iteratorURL">
    <portlet:param name="mvcPath" value="/html/locationaction/view.jsp" />
</liferay-portlet:renderURL>

<ui:search-container delta="5" emptyResultsMessage="There Are No Location" iteratorURL="${iteratorURL}">
    <ui:search-container-results 
    results="<%= LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocations(searchContainer.getStart(),searchContainer.getEnd())%>"
    total="<%= LocationLocalServiceUtil.getLocationsCount() %>"/>

<!-- Showing Error on this line -->        
    <ui:search-container-row className="com.ka.service.model.Location"
    keyProperty="locationId" modelVar="currentLocation"  escapedModel="<%= true %>">

    <ui:search-container-column-text name="Location Id" 
    value="<%=String.valueOf(currentLocation.getLocationId()) %>" />

    </ui:search-container-row>
    <ui:search-iterator/>
</ui:search-container>
```

Comment: Change `className="com.ka.service.model.Location"` to `className="<%=com.ka.service.model.Location %>"` and verify!

Comment: Also, where is the opening tag of `<ui:search-iterator/>`?

Comment: @ParkashKumar : I have updated my Code with yours but giving me same error. I am following this url : http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/05/liferay-search-form-with-search.html

Comment: @ParkashKumar : error got solved by removing the escapedModel attribute. But now some garbage value is printed out on the top of all records.